# How to convert a specific word followed by digits to subscript in a string using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

How to convert a specific word followed by digits to subscript in a string using PHP?

For example,

```
$nutrients = "Vitamin A, Vitamin B1, Vitamin B12, 1-Octamine, 1,2,Hydroxyethyl";
```

The string should be converted as:

```
Vitamin A, Vitamin B<sub>1</sub>, Vitamin B<sub>12</sub>, 1-Octamine, 1,2,Hydroxyethyl
```

(Vitamin A, Vitamin B<sub>1</sub>, Vitamin B<sub>12</sub>, 1-Octamine, 1,2,Hydroxyethyl)

Pattern must match as **Vitamin B***<any digits>*

Comment: Did you try anything? Please share so that we could help you from where you are stuck.

Comment: `~Vitamin B(\d+),~` and `preg_replace_callback()` with `<sub>` tag or a little CSS?

Comment: I tried some like..  $nutrients = preg_replace('~Vitamin B\d*~', ???, $nutrients);

Comment: @chris85 The word may contain one or more digits, like Vitamin B1, Vitamin B3, Vitamin B12... So, it may contain minimum one digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should subscript any number after `Vitamin A-Z`.

```
$nutrients = preg_replace('~(Vitamin [A-Z])(\d+)~', '$1<sub>$2</sub>', $nutrients);
```

The character class might not be needed, is vitamin B the only one that can have subscripts?

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/rR4nN5/1
PHP Demo: https://eval.in/518553

The `+` quantifier requires the preceding character be present, the `*` does not.

e.g.

```
Test\d*
```

matches both:

```
Test
```

and

```
Test123
```

Answer (score 0):

## Regex:

```
(?<=[A-Z])\d+
```

## Substitution:

```
<sub>\0<sub>
```

## Usage

```
$re = "/(?<=[A-Z])\\d+/"; 
$str = "Vitamin A, Vitamin B1, Vitamin B12, 1-Octamine, 1,2,Hydroxyethyl"; 
$subst = "<sub>$0<sub>"; 
 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

## Demo:

Pure Regex: https://regex101.com/r/sG0fE7/1
PHP: https://eval.in/518559

## Explanation

Matches an uppercase letter (using a positive lookbehind so it does not capture it) then any digits after it.  Then substitutes in the `sub` tags around the digits.

Comment: If I try `$str = "Vitamin A, Vitamin B1, Vitamin B12, 1-Octamine, 1,2,Hydroxyethyl A2"; `. It fails

Comment: @ak-SE instead of `[A-Z]` use `Vitamin `.  With this answer I was trying to go for everything possibly instead of just explicit Vitamins which is where that problem comes from.

Comment: [@RedLaser](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2988954/redlaser) Solution given by [@chris85](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4333555/chris85) works fine in any condition.